# Mock IOC Unity Object Creation call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, rhino-mocks

```
public class ExcelHelper : IExcelHelper
{
    private ICustomLoadRepository _customLoadRepository;
    public ExcelHelper(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
         _customLoadRepository= unityContainer.Resolve<ICustomLoadRepository>(); 
    }
}
```

We have started using RhinoMocks to Unit test our code.

Not sure how to mock the code line

```
_customLoadRepository = unityContainer.Resolve<ICustomLoadRepository>();
```

We do not want it be resolved by passing from constructor parameter as number of such parameters sometimes reach more than 7-8 on classes.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

That said, it is generally considered a bad practice to inject the container as a dependency into any class because it defeats the purpose of using dependency injection. Such designs have more in common with the *Service Locator* pattern. Which is considered, in this context, an anti-pattern.

You should instead practice [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.
>   ...
>   Classes with explicit dependencies are more honest.  They state very clearly what they require in order to perform their particular function.

```
public class ExcelHelper : IExcelHelper {
    private readonly ICustomLoadRepository customLoadRepository;

    public ExcelHelper(ICustomLoadRepository customLoadRepository) {
         this.customLoadRepository = customLoadRepository;
    }

    //...
}
```

this can easily be tested by injecting a mock of the abstracted dependency using [Rhino Mocks](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) or any other mocking framework.

```
public void Some_unit_test() {
    //Arrange
    var stubCustomLoadRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICustomLoadRepository>();
    stubCustomLoadRepository.Stub(_ => _.SomeCustomLoadMethod()).Return("Some value");

    var classUnderTest = new ExcelHelper(stubCustomLoadRepository);

    //Act
    //...exercise class under test

    //Assert
    //...
}
```

As for your statement about having many constructor parameters,

> We do not want it be resolved by passing from constructor parameter as the number of such parameters sometimes reach more than 7-8 on each classes

I consider this a code smell. This often indicates that your class is trying to do too many things. A violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](http://deviq.com/single-responsibility-principle/).

So by all indications it appears you have a design issue. Review you classes and try refactoring them with aggregated dependencies. Consider following a more SOLID design principle.